# In applescript, what is an "application process"?

Tags: syntax, applescript

I understand the difference between applications and processes from other questions. But I was hoping I could get a little clarification on what is happening in this bit of code.

```
(application processes whose visible is true)
```

Is "application processes" referring to all processes that are started by an application? Does that mean that there are processes not started by an application? Or could I just switch this to "processes" and take out "application"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`application process` is just sub-class of `process` with a single property, namely the `application file` path.
Using

```
tell application "System Events" to get every process
```

or

```
tell application "System Events" to get every application process
```

you will get an identical list because System Events can only access application processes.

The shell command ps can list all processes, where you can see the difference.

```
do shell script "ps aux"
```

Comment: Ok neat, thanks jwaks. By the way, where does one find all of this kind of information? Is there any documentation that details every specific class such as docs.oracle.com/javase/8/ does for Java?